# Is there a way to write this in F#?

Tags: f#

```
let is_sum_greater_than_10 list =
    list
    |> Seq.filter (filter)
    |> Seq.sum
    |> (10 >)
```

This does not compile. Lookng at the last line "|> (10 >)" is there a way to write this such that the left is pipelined to the right for binary operators?

Thanks

Comment: There are no Haskell-like "operator sections" in F#; use a lambda, as in the last sample of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a partial application of the `<` operator, using the *(operator-symbol)* syntax:

```
let is_sum_greater_than_10 list =
    list
    |> Seq.filter filter
    |> Seq.sum
    |> (<)10
```

You can also see this as an equivalent of a lambda application:

```
let is_sum_greater_than_10 list =
    list
    |> Seq.filter filter
    |> Seq.sum
    |> (fun x y -> x < y)10
```

or just a lambda:

```
let is_sum_greater_than_10 list =
    list
    |> Seq.filter filter
    |> Seq.sum
    |> (fun y -> 10 < y)
```

Comment: No. OP wants a strict comparison.

Comment: I believe that the OP actually wants `(>) 10`, since this would result in the equivalent of `fun x -> 10 > x`.

Comment: @kvb: I don't think so, else OP function name wouldn't be `is_sum_greater_than_10` but rather `is_sum_less_than_10`.

Comment: @Stringer Bell - good point.  I'm confused by the OP's expectation that `(10 >)` might somehow perform that operation...

Comment: Yes, this is why I think using `|> (fun x -> x > 10)` form is the most readable one and therefore preferable (think about developers who will maintain your code, if not yourself).

Comment: In the last example, the parens happen to be optional. `|> fun x -> x > 10` will work just as well.

Comment: The round braces around _filter_ are optional, too.

Comment: @MarceIo Uchimura: Thanks, I will remove them

Answer (score 0):

You can use a slightly modified version of your example, albeit this is in an infix expression notation:

```
let ``is sum greater than 10`` filter list =
    (list
        |> Seq.filter filter
        |> Seq.sum) > 10
```